# Uncaught TypeError: this.element.val is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

could someone help me to solve this error? I rly don't know where I am doing a mistake. I'm new to either JavaScript or OOP, so thanks for your help guys.

Here is my code:

```
Test.prototype.testing= function() {
    var oneDate= new Date();
    var anotherDate= new Date(this.element.val());
    return oneDate.getTime() < anotherDate.getTime();
}
```

I'm receiving this error on line 3:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.element.val is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this refers to the scope of the function itself, it doesn't link to any element. You can try to store the reference of an element outside the function and store it in a variable.

```
var element = document.getElementById('someID');

Test.prototype.testing= function() {
var oneDate= new Date();
var anotherDate= new Date(element.value);
return oneDate.getTime() < anotherDate.getTime();
}
```

I guess you are using jquery, but using vanilla javascript like this is fine too.